# Angular 2 - Can't resolve all parameters for component: (?)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, components

I started an Angular2 app and I have an issue since days !

```
Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?).(…)
```

But my issue is not about a particular provider : Everyting that I try to inject in my HomeComponent constructor return that error. No similars questions on that errors resolved my situation, and now I spent so much time looking for this that I can't find it.

App.moodule.ts :

```js
  import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
  import { SimpleNotificationsModule } from 'angular2-notifications';

  // Controllers
  import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
  import { HomeComponent }  from './components/home.component';

  // Service
  import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

  // Guards
  import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

  @NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: '',
          component: HomeComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }
      ]),
      SimpleNotificationsModule
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
      AuthService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
  })

  export class AppModule { }
```

My HomeComponent :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: '/templates/home.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit 
{
    public test: boolean = false;

    constructor( 
        private _authService: AuthService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.test = true;
    }
}
```

The AuthService that I try to import is empty, and as I said every providers that I inject in HomeComponent return that error. Each constructor argument create a new question mark in the error. Let me know if you need more code, but I don't think the rest (templates, systemjs.config.js...) is the problem

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with imports or project config, not with the code.

Comment: Through about this but what could it be ? Do you want a particular file ? Ps : When I don't put any argument in constructor, it work fine.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I'm not using TS myself and don't know about project configuration.

Comment: is this pointing to correct file? `import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';`

Comment: @Hareesh Yes, my controller dir in which HomeController is, is in the same folder that the "services" dir.

Comment: How does `HomeComponent` relate to 'AppComponent'?

Comment: @joshvito Well if I understand you well, with the router that you can see in app.module, and AppComponent has a router-outlet tag in his template.

Comment: what solved it for me: see forwardref answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters

Comment: It seems to be related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you have

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

in your `tsconfig.js`. You should not need to add `@Inject()` to your function parameters if that's enabled.

Comment: I was facing this problem while developing SharePoint SPFx solution with Angular 5. This saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Truly a lifesaver!

Answer (score 8):

Import this

```
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
```

And change your constructor to

```
constructor(@Inject(AuthService) _authService: AuthService) 
{

}
```

you should @Inject any service into constructor before using it.

and your service should be injectable

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

}
```

Comment: I was having this obscure error message pop up when using an abstract class which I hadn't made `@Injectable`. Adding `@Injectable` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

My problem ended up being nothing. I simply restarted the webpack watcher and then everything was fine. For reference, I'm using the Angular CLI.

Comment: no idea why but that turned out to be my problem too... first made me cold sweaty for a bit cuz I was like "thats supposed to work.. wtf.."

Answer (score 0):

The issue that raised this error for me was completely different.  I had a logging category in the component that I had mistakenly used in the service, and thus the service had a dependency on the component and wasn't able to be created in time for it to be injected into the component.

TL;DR: Check the imports on the service that can't be injected.