# Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular, typescript, sharepoint

I am building an SPFx angular 2 component, that has a nested child component. The child component needs to reference the current context, but if I do:

```
import {
  IWebPartContext
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
```

with

```
constructor(context: IWebPartContext) {
```

I get:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for ...

Alternatively, if I do:

```
constructor(@Inject(context) context: IWebPartContext) {
```

I get:

> SPComponentLoader.loadComponent: ERROR: ***Failed to load entry point
>   from component "ffaa6a0e-9eba-40a0-bec5-226d1db53caf"
>   (RequirementsFormWebPart). DefaultLogHandler.error @
>   DefaultLogHandler.js:15 Log.error @ Log.js:19 (anonymous) @
>   SPSystemJsComponentLoader.js:225 TraceLogger.js:69
>   [1487550303166][Shell.ClientSideWebPartManager]
>   [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part
>   WebPart.RequirementsFormWebPart.7a18b99b-78ca-4d0e-b087-189bbe751b7d,Error:
>   ***Failed to component "ffaa6a0e-9eba-40a0-bec5-226d1db53caf" (RequirementsFormWebPart). Original error:      Error loading
>   https://component-id.invalid/ffaa6a0e-9eba-40a0-bec5-226d1db53caf_0.0.1
>   script resources due to: undefined. CALLSTACK:: Error

Any ideas?

Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with SPFx and Angular5. Adding this inside tsconfig.js solved my issue.
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

Ref:-
[Angular 2 - Can't resolve all parameters for component: (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045508/angular-2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-component?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by not injecting, but rather just needed to instantiate.

```
      public context: IWebPartContext;

      constructor() {
        this.model = new TaxonomyModel(this.context);
      }
```