# Why can AuthHttp (angular2-jwt) not be dependency injected into component?

Tags: angular, typescript

## UPDATE: Solution Found

It was rather simple (although horrendous to find), the configuration was wrong. To get the correct setup I updated my package.json (dependencies section) and tsconfig.json to be similar to the [angular.io sample](https://angular.io/tutorial).

The most notable of these changes were:

- Updating the angular npm packages from "~4.0.0" to "~4.2.0"
- Changing the module in tsconfig.json from "system" to "commonjs"

I do not understand how that changes things, but it works!

## Original Question

### Context

We're attempting to set up the [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) with our Angular2/4 project using the sample configuration in the link. There are two main files:

*app.module.ts*

```
import { AuthConfig, AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './Components/app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, routingComponents],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: (http: Http, options: RequestOptions) => new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http, options),
            deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
        }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "/App/Components/app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent
{
    constructor(service: AuthHttp)
    { }
}
```

### Error

> Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

Looking at the constructor of the AuthHttp class (from the .d.ts file), I have deemed that the likely culprit is that the include for `AuthConfig` is not working correctly, because if I try to create an instance of this class it errors stating the constructor does not exist.

I have found this resource saying I need to read up more on DI, but everything looks alright from my end.
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/88

### Update: Found Extra Information

If the `AppComponent` constructor is changed to call `new AuthConfig()` it generates `new angular2_jwt_1.AuthConfig()` in the transpiled js file (This errors stating the constructor does not exist).
However, if this is changed to `new angular2_jwt_1.default.AuthConfig()` manually in the js file, it creates the instance correctly. Could this be related to the cause?

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your issue, but your imports are like: `import { ... } from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';`, but in lib's README it's just `...from 'angular2-jwt';`.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look at my systemjs.config.js file. Hopefully this error isn't just a case of spot the difference.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. The same error still stands. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact reason I'm having this issue, but it's most likely configuration based. The work around I have employed is to not use the *angular2-jwt* library and instead just add the bearer token to the request manually base of this [angular2 jwt authentication article](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial).

The following is how to obtain the bearer token.

```
public Login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean>
{
    // Prepare post headers
    var headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Prepare credential request
    var body: string = "grant_type=password&scope=scopes go here&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

    return this.http
        .post("token url here", body, { headers: headers })
        .map((response: Response) =>
        {
            let token = response.json();
            token = token && token.access_token;
            if (!token)
                return false;
            else
            {
                localStorage.setItem('username', username);
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

The following is how to make an authenticated request (Token property gets current token from localStorage).

```
public Post<T>(url: string, body: string): Observable<T>
{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.Token });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http
        .post(url, body)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

**I'm still looking for a better solution and an explanation for why it would not work!**

Comment: Hi, I think i ran into similar problems  some time ago, try changing the way you inject the AuthHttp into the AppComponent, see last answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045508/angular-2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-component

Comment: Interesting... emitDecoratorMetadata, @Inject and forwardref seem to do nothing to change it for me. I imagine I have an issue with my package versions or something.