# Is it possible to omit explicit overlapping imports if aldrady imported in parent in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, import

*Not sure if the title is clear enough. Feel free to suggest improvements.*

I've noticed that the components I'm designing tend to have a bunch of imports. Some of them are duplicated in the importing component. Intuitively, I feel that I'm making it work **but** sensing code smell.

Suppose we want a monkey to have a banana.

```
import { Banana } from "./banana";
@Component
export class Monkey { }
```

Now, some dude wants to own a monkey.

```
import { Monkey } from "./monkey";
@Component
export class Dude { }
```

But what if the dude's also hungry and wants a banana for himself too?

```
import { Monkey } from "./monkey";
import { Banana } from "./banana";
@Component
export class Dude { }
```

This seems ineffective and redundant to me. The second import appears superfluous since the dude already has a banana through the monkey.

Is it a proper way to declare the import hierarchy in Angular? Or is there a like-a-boss'y way to decrease the scroll payload when looking into the gazillions of imports in each file?

If there isn't a better way, I'd be delighted to see a motivation for this atrocity for a reference mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export from other files to make identifiers available from multiple files from using a single import:

```
import { Monkey } from "./monkey";
export { Monkey } from "./monkey"; // re-export
@Component
export class Dude { }
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B

This can lead to hard to find errors though if there are cycles.
See [Angular 2 DI Error - EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters/38000323#38000323)

Comment: It depends on the `--module` target. If you use `--module system`, then `Monkey` will only be imported once. If you use `--module commonjs` then two `require` calls are emitted. `system` is a superior format for transpiling as it preserves ES Module semantics with the highest fidelity available, including correct, spec compliant circular reference support.

Comment: Oh boy... That looks even more confusing import/export, hehe. Thanks for the answer. I think I'll keep to the verbose version for now. Any ideas on why it's designed like that?

Comment: Hard for me to answer, because for me it looks quite consistent and logical. Why would you want to have something exported implicitly? 
I guess your expectations depend on where you come from. If you come from a strongly typed language like C#, Java, Go, ... this behavior will be what you expect, if you come from other languages you might be used to different behavior (don't know any myself, but I'm a strong believer in strongly typed).