# Create child components in the parent component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm pretty new to Angular & Typescript. Familiar with OOP & Javascript. And im bit confused as to how to do the following:

I want to create and insert a number of `child` component instances inside the `parent` component depending on a variable in the `parent` component. I also want to give each `child` component values that I pass it from the `parent`. Code below gives me:
`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ParentComponent: (?, ?).`
Which is confusing as hell to me since im passing the correct amount of parameters & correct types?

Parnet Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
      <ul>
      <li *ngFor='let child of collOfChildren'>
          <child></child>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private collOfChildren: Array<ChildComponent> = [];

  numOfChildren = 3;
  childNames = ['Child 1', 'Child 2','Child 3'];

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.numOfChildren; i++) {
      this.collOfChildren.push(new ChildComponent(this.childNames[i],5));
    }
  }

}
```

Child Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  private name:String;
  private age:number;

  constructor(name:String, age:number) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 DI Error - EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular tutorial has correct practice,you do not need to init child components array ,you just need to pass the child data to child component as below:

```
<child *ngFor="let childName of childNames" [name]="childName">
```

And you need add Input decorator to name of childComponnet as below:

```
@Input() name: string;
```