# Ionic 4 and Angular issues in --prod --release

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I am trying to build the ionic 4 application with --prod --release flags. But It shows the white screen with the following error,

I have searched but unable to encrypt this error. The application is working fine during the ng serve and without these flags". How to find what is "L"

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'L'(?, ?, ?). Make sure that
>   all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have a valid type
>   annotations and that 'L' is decorated with Injectable

even I have tried the ionic cordova run browser --prod. Getting the same error with a white screen.

Comment: please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters) may be it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: are you using Leaflet?

Comment: No I am not using the Leaflet.