# Why can't you add a parameter to the constructor when using @Component decorator?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

When I try to add a parameter to the constructor of a class I have an error: "Can't resolve all paremeters for Test c /: Users /....../ test.component.ts :(?).

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector:"app-rueba",
    template: "hola"
})
export class Prueba
{
    n:string;
    constructor(nombre:string)
    {
      this.n=nombre;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?? Excuse me if the answer is pretty obvious I'm pretty new to angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any need of having parameters in the constructor. You are not creating objects from the component like:

```
const object = new MyComponent(param);
```

In Angular, the constructor is used for injecting dependencies. The parameters are dependency injections. There is a difference between class and component. Read more here:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection