# Can't resolve all parameters for Component: (? ? ?)

Tags: angular, multi-module, nested-routes

I am getting this error when I add

constructor(
private fb: FormBuilder
)

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RegisterComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2196)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:17927)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:17823)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:17452)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:18022)
    at compiler.js:18014
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (compiler.js:18013)
    at compiler.js:17984
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Did you import ```ReactiveFormsModule``` in your module?

Comment: Can you paste your component file here , as the error suggests is FormBuilder imported correctly from `@angular/forms`

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters

Comment: in the module where your component is declared you need import ReactiveFormsModule from '@angular/forms'

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy imported formsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts

Comment: @Navitas28  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, RegisterComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class LoginModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Login module loaded...');
  }
 }

Comment: can you import ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule in your LoginModule. It may resolve your problem

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy already done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 3 hours on researching a solution I found this:

In your case, adding `@Injectable()` in front of your component `RegisterComponent`  should fix your problem.