# Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript

when i enable the `constructor` i am getting an error as:

`Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?).` at present i commented.
not able to understand the issue:

Homecomponent.ts :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { switchMap, startWith, catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { GitHubService } from "./../github.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"]
})
export class HomeComponent {
  search = new FormControl("");
  user$ = this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap((value) =>
      this.service.getUser(value).pipe(
        tap(console.log),
        catchError(({ error }) => of(error.errorMessage))
      )
    ),
    startWith("")
  );

  //constructor(private service: GitHubService) {}
}
```

my GitHubService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class GitHubService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(username: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
      .pipe(tap((x) => console.log(x)));
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-chaum-zy5ku?file=/src/app/home/home.component.ts)

Comment: can you try something like `constructor(private abcService: GitHubService)`

Comment: no, same error throws

Comment: Why is your constructor commented out? `this.service` won't work without it.

Comment: If I uncomment, getting an error. that's the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when trying to inject a service into an angular component "EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for component", why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/error-when-trying-to-inject-a-service-into-an-angular-component-exception-can)

Comment: @kian - i do not have circular dependencies in the service. you can check the demo