# Parameter 'day' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Tags: angular

I have this class file in angular `weather.ts` and I have received an error Parameter 'day' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006), which also applied to the data I instantiated (temperature, windspeed, event). Below is the code.

`weather.ts`

```js
export class Weather
{
    day:string;
    temperature:string;
    windspeed:string;
    event:string;
        
    constructor(day, temperature, windspeed, event) //this is where the error occured
        
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.windspeed = windspeed;
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when trying to inject a service into an angular component "EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for component", why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/error-when-trying-to-inject-a-service-into-an-angular-component-exception-can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u must configure your constructor params (set type to each property) like below:

```
constructor(day: string, temperature: string, windspeed: string, event: string)
```

Comment: when vote up answer please)