# TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I started upgrading from Angular 4.4.4 to 5.1.1 today. I have had to upgrade a number of other packages that rely on angular as well. I get an error with so little context that I have no idea where to start. Has anyone else seen this and know what the issue is?

```
$ ng serve --aot=false
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-12-19T15:26:36.137Z
Hash: bf0b773d5dfafdd9133b
Time: 16934ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.93 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 636 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js (scripts) 307 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 4.03 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 855 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at AotSummaryResolver.resolveSummary (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:32638:56)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadSummary (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14825:66)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15857:66)
    at C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15323:55
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15323:18)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15157:52)
    at C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15245:72
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15230:49)
    at visitLazyRoute (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31061:104)
    at AotCompiler.listLazyRoutes (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31029:20)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.listLazyRoutes (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:156:30)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\source\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:44:36)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\source\app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:248:66)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\source\app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:562:50)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I find it strange that it starts in `AotSummaryResolver` when I have --aot=false in the serve command.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot=false",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.0.42",
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.1.1",
    "@schematics/angular": "^0.1.11",
    "@schematics/schematics": "^0.0.11",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "echarts": "^3.6.0",
    "echarts-gl": "^1.0.0-alpha.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.11.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-action": "^3.2.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "yarn": "^0.24.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.1",
    "@types/d3": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/echarts": "^0.0.6",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.23",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.33",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.12.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typemoq": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

My angular-cli version is 1.6.1.

The error seems to occur here in the angular source code:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b3eb1db6dd57a0820cfc94af5460ceb3fea20610/packages/compiler/src/aot/summary_resolver.ts#L68

### SOLUTION

Previously I thought it was related to ng-bootstrap which was incorrect.

I found some context for it by putting a console log at line 15207 in compiler.umd.js as follows:

```
if (meta.entryComponents) {
    console.log(meta);
    entryComponents.push.apply(entryComponents, flattenAndDedupeArray(meta.entryComponents)
                .map(function (type) { return /** @type {?} */ ((_this._getEntryComponentMetadata(type))); }));
}
```

Which resulted in:

```
...
entryComponents: [ undefined ],
...
```

I had a module with `entryComponents: [MdProgressSpinner]` where `MdProgressSpinner` was not imported. When I removed it that error went away... and the next one came :)

Comment: did you test your code prior to make sure it worked before the upgrade?

Comment: That's a lot of third party angular-specific packages. Since this is a version change (breaking change) you'll need to ensure that all of those packages support the new version. (ng-boostrap, ng-idle, ngrx, schematics, angular2-counto, etc)

Comment: @MikeTung Yes, I ran it right before the upgrade.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Seems to be related to ng-bootstrap. I logged out some info in the compiler and I see an undefined coming in. I downgraded to their recommended version (5.0.2) and now I get "Cannot read property 'assertNoMembers' of undefined" :)

Comment: Solved the issue by removing an undefined entry component. A better error message would have been nice!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

One of the reasons this can happen is in you app module, you have an entry components which the build process can't find a import for (in below example if I comment out the import line and leave the component then it causes this error).[image]

[image]

Comment: One reason this can apparently happen is the spread operator. If you want to use entry components from an array declared elsewhere, use concat.

Comment: @BarryMcNamara thanks!  That was my issue.  Using concat worked.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and nearly gave up. Your question contained the tip that helped me pinpoint the problem, but I totally missed it because it was part of the question.

Put a console log at line 15258 in compiler.umd.js (or whatever exact line your error points you to):

`if (meta.entryComponents) {
    console.log(meta); //<== Add this`

My console log contained the following at the end:
{ ngMetadataName: 'NgModule',
  declarations: [ **null** ], ...   entryComponents: [ **null** ] }

The issue turned out to be a Module that imported a class like this:

`import MyComponent from "./my-component.component.ts";`

The class was exported using **default**:

`export default class MyComponent { ...`

Removing `default`, and adding curly brackets to the import worked!

`import { MyComponent } from "./my-component.component.ts";`

Comment: Yes, I still cannot get why it affects only dynamic components, but export default doesnt work

Comment: Thank you for saving me a ton of time!

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error message when creating a new **library**. It turned out that in public_api.ts of that library, I was importing an **index.ts** file. This type of bundle are still not handle well. Making separate imports to each file to expose the public API was the solution in my case.

Comment: i have this problem in library . how you resolve that can you explain ?

Comment: I simply removed the index.ts files and replaced them by making the imports using full relative path. As an example, instead of importing via the index file such as "import { MyComponent } from './components'", you should import directly such as "import { MyComponent } from './components/my-component.ts'"

Comment: Worked for me!! This should be the answer I think. did you created any ticket for this?

Comment: I had the same problem, thank you for pointing that out!

https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/pull/5705/files

import { IgxGridComponent } from '../grid'; 
.. to
import { IgxGridComponent } from '../grid/grid.component';

Comment: Hi Laurent, do you mean you were using the ["barrel"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html) style of import ([archived link](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/glossary.html#!#B))? And it sounds like you did same as Gunther here, ["Import it from the file where it is declared directly instead of the barrel."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000323/1175496) ?  For reference 1) Angular once discouraged barrels, but the [links are all broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48454885/1175496), 2) barrels are OK, but instead, can use Angular `NgModule` to re-export.

Comment: Another [link about "barrels" (`index.ts`) file failing, due to the order of the `export` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902476/automatic-ordering-of-exports-in-index-ts-makes-app-crash/37907696#37907696)

Comment: Confirming this is helpful :) Got rid of index.ts for Components (only) and it was enough. Seems like referencing Components in `EntryComponents` does not make friends with index.ts usage in public-api.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked out the project from an already working application in a repository, check if you have a build script defined in package.json and execute it before invoking `ng serve`